# Validation errors not showing up - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

For some reason validation errors are not showing up.

my form

```
<%= form_for [@question.category, @question] do |f| %>

  <% if @question.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@question.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this question from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @question.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="field panel">
    <%= f.label :question_type %><br>
    <%= f.select :question_type, [ ["single","single"],["multiple","multiple"] ], selected: f.object.question_type %>
  </div>
  <div class="field panel">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field panel">
    <%= f.label :image %><br>
    <% if @question.image? %>
      <div class="explanation-image text-center">
        <%= image_tag @question.image_url(:resized) %>
        <p>
          <label>
            <%= f.check_box :remove_image %>
            Remove image
          </label>
        </p>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :image_cache %>
  </div>
  <div class="field panel">
    <%= f.label :explanation %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :explanation, size: "30x10" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field panel">
    <%= f.label :link_name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :link_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field panel">
    <%= f.label :link_url %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :link %>
  </div>
  <div class="field panel">
    <%= f.label :video_url %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :video_url %>
  </div>
  <div class="field panel">
    <%= f.label :category_id %><br><%= @category.title %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :category_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <br>
    <%= f.submit 'Submit', class:"button round success" %> <%= link_to 'Back', category_questions_path, class: "button round alert" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

this is the model

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :choices
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  validates :description, length: {
    minimum: 6
  }
  validates :link, presence: true
end
```

and parts of the controller

```
def edit
  @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
  @question = @category.questions.find_by(id: params[:id])
end

def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @question.update(question_params)
      format.html { redirect_to category_question_url(@question.category, @question), notice: 'Question was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @question }
    else
      format.html {
        @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
        @question = @category.questions.find_by(id: params[:id])
        render action: :edit
      }
      format.json { render json: @question.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

the error messages code is directly from the scaffolding. i haven't touched it. if i try to edit a question and save it while lets say link field is empty it will reload the edit action correctly but no error message will pop up.

Any clues?

Comment: The error messages are not showing only when editing or when creating too?

Comment: its a combined form both actions (create and edit) so yes it does not work for both...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it fails to save, you redefine the @question variable, before rendering out the page.

```
@question = @category.questions.find_by(id: params[:id])
```

this will delete the object which failed to save and was holding the validation errors, and replace it with the one loaded out of the database.  Don't do this.  I think if you just delete this line it might work ok.